# Ringer and Notification Volume

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, htc, volume-control, vibration

Before icecream sandwich, on my HTC I was able to make my notification volume on zero (so it would vibrate) while my ringer was at full volume. Now with icecream sandwich the ringer and notification volumes are to be set at the same level. Is there any way to put the notification volume back to vibrate while there is still volume for the ringer?

Comment: For what it's worth,  Jellybean lets you control them independently.

Comment: It looks like you might be stuck. Even when I use an app which purports to allow controlling the ring and notification volume separately, when I re-open the app the two settings are in lock-step. I think with stock ICS you're not going to be able to do it.

Comment: @offby1: I read that in the Jellybean features, but can't seem to accomplish it on 4.1.2 with a Nexus S.

Comment: I think I was wrong -- I just looked at my phone running 4.1.2, and it shows "Ringtons and notifications" as one of the three volumes that you can control.