# Android 4.04: Default Silent Mode to Mute

Tags: volume-control, mute

I just upgraded Galaxy S2 (Epic 4G Touch) to Android 4.04. In the previous version, I could change the Default Silent Mode to Mute instead of Vibrate in the Sound settings. I believe this was under Vibrate settings; this could be changed to Never.

In this version, if I hold down the power button and choose Silent Mode it always goes to Vibrate mode instead of Mute. I can change the setting to Mute by going into the Sound settings, but it is much faster to hold down the power button (particularly when the phone is locked).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please see the following Q&As, which cover your question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25816/completely-mute-my-android-phone / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13352/is-there-a-one-click-widget-to-make-my-phone-completely-silent / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8573/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-turn-the-phone-into-silent-mode

Comment: Izzy, those posts apply to the old version of the software. My question is based on the new version, which doesn't contain those features.

Comment: Ah -- thanks for pointing this out. I couldn't tell so from your question, hence the suggestions. Neither having a Sammy nor ICS, I cannot help further -- so hopefully someone else tunes in (one of those who had the problem formerly, see the links, might have upgraded, too).

Comment: Gotcha, I edited the title of my question to make this a bit clearer. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps it is a change from 4.0.3 or earlier to this version 4.0.4 to make its way into the 4.1 code base as in Jellybean. Somone else asked this similar question about it on Jellybean and was enquiring that the sound functionality was changed from ICS to JB.

Comment: Here's the question pertaining to my comment above ... http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26476/ringer-and-notification-volume

Comment: This works better on my SG3 on 4.1.2. One can easily mute by holding down power button while phone is locked.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using the power button long press for the Device Options menu in 4.0.4 on SG2. It always reverts back to "Vibrate" when changing Silent mode, albeit it is possible to press the volume down until it goes into vibrate, and then press volume down again. This takes a bit of time, though, and doesn't work unless you're past the screen lock. IMO, in a perfect world, this should only take one action.

**Conclusion**

Wait for a version update above 4.0.4 and hope they fix this BS. (Also, I friggin' hate people who think their phone is silent during meetings or seminars, and their phone just keeps buzzing and buzzing and buzzing. It's #*@!ing Android trolling!)

**Hack**

The only hack I've found to make it work with the power button long press is going to Setting > Sound > Vibration intensity and setting ringtone vibration to zero. However, I'm pretty sure that turns off vibration globally, and you'll still see that annoying icon for "silence with vibration" when you use Silent mode trough the power button. :(

**Fastest way to mute**

Wipe off the screen lock. Flip down the curtain of the notificaions menu, then double tap the sound icon. That will bring you from sound to vibrate, and finally to mute. Or get a widget for muting.

Comment: I agree with the fastest way to mute, double tapping the sound icon from within the notifications menu. Again, in previous versions of my OS on the SG2, this could be done without unlocking the phone, which was handy.

Answer (score 0):

I own a Xperia phone with ICS 4.0.4, and have no problems going into silent mode (mute).

Quick ways to go into silent mode (muting the phone):

- holding the volume down until vibrate mode, then releasing the volume down and pressing it again once more until silent mode (mute)
- holding the power/lock button until a screen appears, then selecting silent mode (mute)

Other ways of muting the phone:

- going into the `Settings > Sound` and selecting `Silent Mode > Mute`
- going into the `Settings > Volumes` and completely sliding down the volume bar for calls via `Ringtone & notifications`

Answer (score 0):

if you scroll down the menu bar you can switch from sound to vibrate to silent to sound. THis is easy enough for me, isn't it?
Andreas

Comment: What menu bar are you referring do? Can you be more specific?

Comment: This feature isn't available on every Android device

Comment: If by menu bar you mean the side button, yes, I agree when the phone is unlocked. When the phone is locked, the button does not behave that way.

In the previous version, the Disable Sound function, enabled when holding the power button, would respect the setting regarding Vibrate.